# How to use -auth in terminal's dscl tool

Tags: macos, mac, bash, authentication

I am trying to find out how to authenicate a user.
I am using bash-3.2# if that makes a difference.
when typing:

`dscl`

it shows

`Entering interactive mode...`

`>`

then after typing this:

`-auth testuser`

it comes like this:

`Password:`

but no matter what I type or what name the user is or what passcode i put in, it still ends up saying:

`Authentication for node No Node failed. (-14090, eDSAuthFailed)`

`<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14090 (eDSAuthFailed)`

`>`

How do I auth this user?

Answer (score 0):

For Local:

```
/usr/bin/dscl . auth username password
```

For Directory, replace '.' with the path to the directory (in dscl parlance).

```
/usr/bin/dscl '/Active Directory/domain.corp.com' auth username password
```

Comment: this makes no sense to me, what do you type? in which order?